# JavaMail IMAP folder search limitation in the number of messages returned?

Tags: jakarta-mail, imap

Could someone help me to clarify the following matter? Thanks

```
LocalDate localDate = LocalDate.now().minusDays(600);
SearchTerm newer = new SentDateTerm(ComparisonTerm.GE,            
    Date.from(localDate.atStartOfDay(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()));
Message[] messages = inbox.search(newer);
```

The messages returned only 1000 messages, actually, I have > 1000 messages in the mailbox. Do we have a limitation on this?

Debug log:
    DEBUG: setDebug: JavaMail version 1.5.6
    DEBUG: getProvider() returning javax.mail.Provider[STORE,imap,com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore,Oracle]
    DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.fetchsize: 16384
    DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.ignorebodystructuresize: false
    DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.statuscachetimeout: 1000
    DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.appendbuffersize: -1
    DEBUG IMAP: mail.imap.minidletime: 10
    DEBUG IMAP: closeFoldersOnStoreFailure
    DEBUG IMAP: trying to connect to host "imap.secureserver.net", port 143, isSSL false
    * OK [CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT STARTTLS ID CHILDREN NAMESPACE IDLE UIDPLUS] Courier-IMAP ready. Copyright 1998-2004 Double Precision, Inc.  See COPYING for distribution information.
    DEBUG IMAP: protocolConnect login, host=imap.secureserver.net, user=xxx(edited), password=
    DEBUG IMAP: mechanism PLAIN not supported by server
    DEBUG IMAP: mechanism LOGIN not supported by server
    DEBUG IMAP: mechanism NTLM not supported by server
    DEBUG IMAP: mechanism XOAUTH2 disabled by property: mail.imap.auth.xoauth2.disable
    DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command trace suppressed
    DEBUG IMAP: LOGIN command result: A0 OK LOGIN Full IMAP support is enabled
    A1 CAPABILITY
    * CAPABILITY IMAP4rev1 UNSELECT STARTTLS ID CHILDREN NAMESPACE IDLE UIDPLUS
    A1 OK CAPABILITY completed
    DEBUG IMAP: connection available -- size: 1
    A2 EXAMINE INBOX
    * FLAGS (\Draft \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen)
    * OK [PERMANENTFLAGS (\Draft \Answered \Flagged \Deleted \Seen)] Limited
    * 92611 EXISTS
    * 0 RECENT
    * OK [UIDVALIDITY 1] Ok
    * OK [UIDNEXT 116157] Predicted next UID
    A2 OK [READ-ONLY] EXAMINE completed.
    A3 SEARCH SENTSINCE 19-Aug-2016 ALL
    * SEARCH 91612 91613 91614 91615 91616 91617 91618 91619 91620 91621 ...
    A3 OK SEARCH done.
    DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup, force false
    DEBUG IMAP: close folder
    A4 CLOSE
    A4 OK mailbox closed.
    DEBUG IMAP: added an Authenticated connection -- size: 1
    A5 LOGOUT
    * BYE IMAP server shutting down
    A5 OK LOGOUT completed
    DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup done
    DEBUG IMAP: IMAPStore cleanup, not connected

Comment: Not in JavaMail.  Maybe in your server.  What does the [JavaMail debug output](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/FAQ#debug) show?  What server are you using?

Comment: @BillShannon : I am using a mailbox which is provided by "godaddy". I attached debug logs, could you please help to review? Thanks

Comment: You can see the SEARCH command that JavaMail sends and the SEARCH response from the server.  If there are messages that meet the search criteria and the server isn't returning them, you need to contact the server vendor.

Comment: Ok thanks @BillShannon, it looks like an issue from IMAP server, not JavaMail. I will take a look in my server....